# FATAL: role "my_name" does not exist on postgres.app on OS X

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, fatal-error, postgresql-9.2

totally new to postgres trying to run postregs.app v9.2.2.0 on OS X 10.8.4

I run the application and get the elephant on the bar, but when I select "Open psql", all I have is:

> host-002:~ lucamoiana$
>   /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql ; exit; psql:
>   FATAL:  role "lucamoiana" does not exist logout
>
> [Process completed]

Where "lucamoiana" is the Admin on my Macbook.

Can you help ? I'm stuck

Thnx

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the terminal and writing the following command:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql postgres
```